# Is it possible to commuincate over UDP?

Tags: ros, communication

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For latency and timing issues is there a way to switch from TCP to UDP? If so how do you do it?

Thanks,
Steven

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12791/is-it-possible-to-commuincate-over-udp?/) by [smarks86](https://answers.ros.org/users/1705/smarks86/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-01-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should pass TransportHints().unreliable() to subscribe. If possible, it is supposed to use UDP.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4